# Camel + Tomcat + Datasource + JNDI = Impossible

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Spring app that runs in Tomcat and connects okay to a JNDI configured datasource. I'm trying to get my Apache Camel app to do the same.

Tomcat context.xml

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/deapplication-datasource" name="jdbc/deapplication-datasource" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/deapplication-datasource" 
    auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    maxTotal="50" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" 
    username="yada" password="nada" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//test-cluster:1521/foo.bar.ca"/>
```

camel-config.xml

```
<!-- JNDI connection fails with Tomcat localhost (works in our testing/WebLogic environment -->
<bean id="dataSourceHello" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/deapplication-datasource"/>
</bean>

<!-- manual config works 
<bean id="dataSourceHello" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//test-cluster:1521/foo.bar.ca" />
    <property name="username" value="yada" />
    <property name="password" value="nada" />
</bean>
-->
```

Java/Camel code:

```
from("direct:healthCheckDb")
        .log("0")
        .setBody(simple("select * from dual"))
        .log("1")
        .to("jdbc:dataSourceHello")
        .log("2")
```

Tomcat log:

```
2022-06-13 12:07:49,879 INFO - 0 
2022-06-13 12:07:49,881 INFO - 1 
2022-06-13 12:07:50,444 ERROR - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-IT-DEV-VM-112-1655147269874-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-IT-DEV-VM-112-1655147269874-0-1). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-IT-DEV-VM-112-1655147269874-0-1] 
2022-06-13 12:07:50,456 ERROR - null org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-IT-DEV-VM-112-1655147269874-0-1]
```

Tomcat and the app start up okay, but when I hit the restful path to test healthCheckDb it fails after log 1 but before log 2 (as you probably noticed above). The same statement works if I use the manual configured datasource. But I'd prefer to use the same setup as we use for WebLogic so I don't have to keep uncommenting and commenting the camel-config.xml file.

(Side note: after hours of research, have not seen 2 web pages agree on how to configure Tomcat JNDI for a datasource).

Possible to get Camel working with JNDI?

Comment: I followed your different steps on Tomcat 9.0.56 with Camel 3.18-SNAPSHOT and postgres instead of Oracle and it worked. I also used a timer instead of a direct endpoint `from("timer://myTimer?fixedRate=true&period=1000")`

Comment: If I could get my company to switch to postgres I would...

Comment: Yes but at least you could test with another database to check if it is Oracle related or not

Comment: Thanks for giving that a try Nicolas;